# Parse field form xml clob

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Ciao,

i've one problem with sql.
I've some table with datatype clob where is stored a clob.
In the same table if we have the xml format we use one function for take the xml_fied

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gettagvalue (
XMLBody IN CLOB, TagXml IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
 return TO_CHAR (SUBSTR (XMLBody,
                        INSTR (XMLBody, '<'||TagXml||'>') + length(TagXml) + 2,
                          INSTR (XMLBody, '</'||TagXml||'>')
                        - INSTR (XMLBody, '<'||TagXml||'>')
                        - (length(TagXml) + 2)
                       )
               );
END GetTagValue;
/
```

example :

```
Select errorhandler.GetTagValue(xml_content,'ORDERID')
from table_order
```

On the same table we have also some xml in json.

How i can create a copy of same function for take the field?
On xml is eay because we have the field with same name that start with  and finish with  but with json

I cannot understand how define the end of field

Comment: I don't understand. You have a CLOB column in a table, and in that column, in some rows, the value is an XML document, and in other rows it's a JSON string? In the same column of the same table? **WHY?** The first thing you should do (or your team, or boss, or whoever) is to replace this single column with two separate columns - one for XML, the other for JSON. Then: for the XML documents, why don't you use XML functions? Using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` on an XML document is unsafe (you may get wrong answers). Similarly on JSON strings you should use JSON specific functions.

Comment: The table is a log table.Some flow in tibco bw5 wrute on xml , the flow on tibco bw6 write json. With substr and instr on xml we dont'have problem..we use the function from 2006

Comment: Fully agreed wuth @mathguy. This function you using is not really gets XML values, just returns first matched `<SomeTag>...</SomeTag>`.

Comment: The function that we use work properly with xml ..we need create a new function for jason..but we don't understand how define where one tag start and where finished.           {"header":{"sourceChannel":"APP","transactionId":"0a669585-9072-4181-881d-74c99d080843","sessionId":"fe679c8e-a499-447e-acb4-2f527cd49ea4","status":"1","errorcode":"EAI-003","errordescription":"Si e' verificato un problema tecnico. Ti invitiamo a riprovare piu' tardi. Se il problema persiste contatta l'Assistenza Clienti e fornisci il codice errore 003"}}

Comment: We dont' understand who take, for example, only APP on fied source. We cannot edit the code, but we need create one function for it

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XML or JSON that you are trying to parse and what values you are trying to extract from the CLOB?

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** try to parse XML or JSON as strings; use a proper XML or JSON parser.

If you have the table with the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  xml CLOB,
  json CLOB CHECK ( json IS JSON )
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( xml, json ) VALUES (
  '<a><b>BBB</b><c>CCC</c><d>DDD</d></a>',
  '{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb","c":[1,2,3,4],"d":"ddd"}'
);
```

Then you can get the `c` values from both using the `XMLQUERY` or `JSON_QUERY` functions:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
          '*/c/text()'
          PASSING XMLTYPE(xml)
          RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS c_xml_value,
       JSON_QUERY(
         json,
         '$.c'
         RETURNING VARCHAR2(50)
       ) AS c_json_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | C_XML_VALUE | C_JSON_VALUE |
> | :---------- | :----------- |
> | CCC         | [1,2,3,4]    |
> ```

If you have XML and JSON values in the same column then look at whether the first character is `<` or not and use the appropriate parsing function; do not try and create your own function to parse the values using substring matching.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT '<a><b>BBB</b><c>CCC</c><d>DDD</d></a>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb","c":[1,2,3,4],"d":"ddd"}' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN value LIKE '<%'
       THEN CAST(
              XMLQUERY( '*/c/text()' PASSING XMLTYPE(value) RETURNING CONTENT )
              AS VARCHAR2(50)
            )
       ELSE JSON_QUERY( value, '$.c' RETURNING VARCHAR2(50) )
       END AS c_value
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | C_VALUE   |
> | :-------- |
> | CCC       |
> | [1,2,3,4] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=59b61400c4b398b1cb298cb012947e83)*

**Update**

You can also use `JSON_TABLE` and `XMLTABLE` to get all the values out:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE( j.sourceChannel, x.sourceChannel ) AS sourceChannel,
       COALESCE( j.transactionId, x.transactionId ) AS transactionId,
       COALESCE( j.sessionId, x.sessionId ) AS transactionId,
       COALESCE( j.status, x.status ) AS status,
       COALESCE( j.errorcode, x.errorcode ) AS errorcode,
       COALESCE( j.errordescription, x.errordescription ) AS errordescription
FROM   table_name t
       OUTER APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.header'
         COLUMNS (
           sourceChannel    VARCHAR2( 50) PATH '$.sourceChannel',
           transactionId    VARCHAR2( 50) PATH '$.transactionId',
           sessionId        VARCHAR2( 50) PATH '$.sessionId',
           status           VARCHAR2( 50) PATH '$.status',
           errorcode        VARCHAR2( 50) PATH '$.errorcode',
           errordescription VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.errordescription'
         )
       ) j
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT *
         FROM   XMLTABLE(
                  '/header'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE( value )
                  COLUMNS
                    sourceChannel    VARCHAR2( 50) PATH 'sourceChannel',
                    transactionId    VARCHAR2( 50) PATH 'transactionId',
                    sessionId        VARCHAR2( 50) PATH 'sessionId',
                    status           VARCHAR2( 50) PATH 'status',
                    errorcode        VARCHAR2( 50) PATH 'errorcode',
                    errordescription VARCHAR2(200) PATH 'errordescription'
                )
       ) x
       ON ( t.value LIKE '<%' )
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT '<header>
  <sourceChannel>xaaa</sourceChannel>
  <transactionId>xbbb</transactionId>
  <sessionId>xccc</sessionId>
  <status>xddd</status>
  <errorcode>xeee</errorcode>
  <errordescription>xfff</errordescription>
</header>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"header":{"sourceChannel":"jaaa","transactionId":"jbbb","sessionId":"jccc","status":"jddd","errorcode":"jeee","errordescription":"jfff"}}' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SOURCECHANNEL | TRANSACTIONID | TRANSACTIONID | STATUS | ERRORCODE | ERRORDESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xaaa | xbbb | xccc | xddd | xeee | xfff |
| jaaa | jbbb | jccc | jddd | jeee | jfff |

Comment: I've try with this json {"header":{"sourceChannel":"APP","transactionId":"0a669585-9072-4181-881d-74c99d080843","sessionId":"fe679c8e-a499-447e-acb4-2f527cd49ea4","status":"1","errorcode":"EAI-003","errordescription":"Si e' verificato un problema tecnico. Ti invitiamo a riprovare piu' tardi. Se il problema persiste contatta l'Assistenza Clienti e fornisci il codice errore 003"}}  using thsi query json_query(xml_content, '$.header.errorcode') json_metadata
 and also json_query(xml_content, '$.errorcode') json_metadata but is null

Comment: @RobertoVinci I can't immediately work out what the issue is with `JSON_QUERY` but all the data comes out with `JSON_TABLE` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b599faf54ff9acbd45ad04e7f802f282)